# Angular2 (beta) valueChanges.subscribe not tracing result in console

Tags: angular, beta

I am going through an Angular2 course in which parts are a little out of date.

I have this simple code for a form with one single input field. As the user types text in the input field, that text should be logged in the console but I get nothing and not even an error warning! I believe it's a syntax issue but no matter what suggestion I have come across online I simply cannot get it to output the text to the console. Here's the code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <input type="text" #search class="form-control">
    </form>
})

export class AppComponent {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            search:  []
        });

        var search = this.form.controls['search'];
        search.valueChanges
            .subscribe( x => { console.log(x) });
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control and the element are not connected.

Add `formControlName="search"`

```
<input type="text" formControlName="search" #search class="form-control">
```